# What is the major differences between Convert.ChangeType or Convert.ToInt32?

Tags: c#

Is there any performance benefits of one over another among Convert.ChangeType or Convert.ToInt32 or int.Parse

Comment: Don't forget about `Int32.TryParse(String, out int)` which gives a few nice possibilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know you're going to be converting a `string` to `Int32`, using `Convert.ChangeType` seems an obscure way of doing that. I would definitely prefer either of the other calls to that.

The main difference between `int.Parse` and `Convert.ToInt32(x)` is that `Convert.ToInt32(null)` returns 0 where as `int.Parse(null)` will throw an exception. Of course, `int.Parse` also gives you more control in terms of what culture is used.

I very much doubt that there's any performance benefit of one over the other: I would *expect* `Convert.ToInt32` to call `int.Parse` rather than the other way round - but it's not *documented* to work that way, and the hit of a single method call is unlikely to be significant. (It may well be inlined anyway.)

Comment: Both Convert.ToInt32() and Int32.Parse() use the (not publicly available) method System.Number.ParseInt32() which in turn invokes System.Number.StringToNumber(). How do I know this? Look at the stack trace of the FormatException that is generated when passing an invalid string :-)

Comment: @user532870: Fair enough - but I still wouldn't rely on that sort of thing :)

Comment: @user532870: Jon is right. reflection shows that Convert.ToInt32 calls int.Parse which calls Number.ParseInt32. @Jon: So int.Parse is better?

Comment: @naveen: It depends on what exact behaviour you want. If you're happy with it using the current culture and you want it to return 0 for null, use Convert.ToInt32. If you want the behaviour of int.Parse, use that :)

Answer (score 5):

```
private const int maxValue = 1000000;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] strArray = new string[maxValue];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxValue; i++)
        {
            strArray[i] = i.ToString();
        }
        int[] parsedNums = new int[maxValue];
        CalcChangeTypePerf(strArray,parsedNums);
        CalcToInt32Perf(strArray, parsedNums);
        CalcIntParse(strArray, parsedNums);
    }
    public static void CalcChangeTypePerf(string[] strArray,int[] parsedArray)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxValue; i++)
        {
            parsedArray[i] = (int)Convert.ChangeType(strArray[i], typeof(int));
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} on CalcChangeTypePerf", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    public static void CalcToInt32Perf(string[] strArray, int[] parsedArray)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxValue; i++)
        {
            parsedArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[i]);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} on CalcToInt32Perf", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    public static void CalcIntParse(string[] strArray, int[] parsedArray)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxValue; i++)
        {
            parsedArray[i] = int.Parse(strArray[i]);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} on CalcIntParse", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

This simple test results this

```
266 on CalcChangeTypePerf
167 on CalcToInt32Perf
165 on CalcIntParse
```

Comment: You're creating a million objects in each test, unnecessarily. While each test is "equal" in that way, it means the relative differences in actual *parsing* time are masked somewhat, and there could be garbage collection within one test, cleaning up garbage from another. I suggest you create an array of strings *once* at the start and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Convert.ToInt32 is better than using Convert.ChangeType for same purpose.

ChangeType is a general-purpose conversion method that converts the object specified by value to conversionType. While ToInt32 is specific for int32 type.

Comment: In fact, `ChangeType()` is programmatic `cast`, meanwhile `Convert.ToInt32()` really creates `int` from other type

Answer (score 0):

Simple test shows `Parse()` is fastest method, next `Convert.ToInt32()` and last `Convert.ChangeType()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "104563";
    int a = 1;

    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
    {
        Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            a = (int)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(int));
        w.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("ChangeType={0}", w.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Stopwatch w1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            a = Convert.ToInt32(s);
        w1.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("ToInt32={0}", w1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Stopwatch w2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            a = Int32.Parse(s);
        w2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Parse={0}", w2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Result is:

```
ChangeType=2422
ToInt32=1859
Parse=1760
ChangeType=2374
ToInt32=1857
Parse=1762
ChangeType=2378
ToInt32=1860
Parse=1763
ChangeType=2375
ToInt32=1855
Parse=1759
```